# regular expression patterns for catching client side attacks

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I need to prevent any of client side javascript attacts(xss,csrf), how can i validate an expression with preg_match in php? Is there any regular expression patterns for catching client side attacks? Or is there other recommended ways to do this?

Comment: What's your input? HTML from a user that you're going to show to another user?

Comment: Not html, but simple text. Explanatation of a word. I am writing an online dictionary.

Comment: @ user: That's easy, then, see machineaddict's answer. If you're just putting the text in the content of an element, `htmlspecialchars` actually does more work than necessary (all you really need to do is change `&` to `&amp;` and `<` to `&lt`, in that order), but the extra work is harmless, and moreover it's important and useful if you use the text as an attribute value (for instance, `title="user text here"`).

Comment: @ user: If you like. It's not necessary, `htmlspecialchars` does all the ones you *need* to do. `htmlentities` will produce larger pages for your users to download, although probably not by enough that it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many tutorials on the web, the best solution I found fit was Opencart's solution to change the global variables before loading the controller:

```
$data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

I never saw someone breaking it.
Link to [the class](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/request.php).

This way the code becomes entity and it's not executable code, like  tags. The user will actually see the code and the browser will not execute it.